# iOS 6.1 AudioQueueStop, AudioQueueDispose error

Tags: objective-c, ios6, audioqueue

Using Audio Queue for my iOS App, I have some problem with a test on iOS6.1, though it has worked fine on iOS6.

The problem is **AudioQueueStop** and **AudioQueueDispose** don't return immediately, or sometimes they crash.

Like this:

```
if (_audioQueue)
{
  auto err = AudioQueueStop(_audioQueue, true);   // Some delay before return
  for (int i = 0; i < kNumberAudioQueueBuffers; i++) {
    AudioQueueFreeBuffer(_audioQueue, _audioQueueBuffer[i]);
  }    
  err = AudioQueueDispose(_audioQueue, true);    // This also has delay
  _audioQueue = nil;
}
```

This isn't called on main thread but another thread, but other stuffs such as **AudioQueueNewoutput** and **AudioQueueStart** also called on that thread.

Actually I tried to run a simple app which uses AudioQueue as a test and in that case it worked fine (on both of iOS6 and 6.1). So other parts in my codes might affect but I couldn't figure out.

Is there anyone who had similar problems and hopefully fixed?

Comment: I have just the same issue. In my case AudioQueueDispose will not return at all. Have you filled a bug report to Apple? Please, let me know if you figured this out

Comment: Sorry for late response. In my case the problem was the timing of my callback function which I registered to AudioQueue. I used mutex mechanism and it caused deadlock. It didn't happen on iOS6 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing similar issues with AudioQueueSetProperty() and kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie. My app crashes *every single time* this is called, when it worked fine on iOS 6.0 and earlier. I'm thinking Apple messed up the audio queue implementation in 6.1.